# Tensor Notation ambiguity

Tags: notation, tensor-products, tensor-decomposition

Sorry for this silly question, but this notation keeps popping up in my face in too many different places without any clarification, so I will be so grateful if someone can help and answer my question:
Does the following notation

$\alpha_{[\mu_1...\mu_p}\beta_{\nu_1...\nu_q]}$

mean this

$\alpha_{[\mu_1...\mu_p]}\beta_{[\nu_1...\nu_q]}$

where the square brackets are the antisymmetrization brackets?

Please help, I need to know and it's driving me crazy!

Answer (score 2):

No, it means that you should antisymmetrize the expression over all indices $\mu_1 \dots \mu_p \nu_1 \dots \nu_q$.

For example, $\alpha_{[\mu} \beta_{\nu]} = \frac12 (\alpha_\mu \beta_\nu - \alpha_\nu \beta_\mu)$ (or maybe without the factor $1/2$, depending on which convention you use).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I wish I could vote you up. But this answer creates trouble for me, which I will explain in my next question.